# Possible to assign order to account?

Tags: shopware6

Is it possible to assign an order manually in the backend to a customer?

I couldn't find anything about it.
Unfortunately this is a regular task of our customer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a new order manually](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/orders/create-order-in-admin) in the administration.

You can't however retroactively change the customer of an order placed via the storefront, if that is what you meant. In theory you could do it programmatically by replacing customer specific associations of the order with new ones, based on another customer. It's still likely this would come with a few undesired side effects though.

Comment: Thanks, this was what i meant, yes. Sad, that it is not possible. Would be a nice feature for shopware core in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean: You want to create a order for a customer via the administration. For this, have a look into the docs:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/orders/create-order-in-admin